# How to debug the changes made in application on titanium without relaunching the application?

Tags: titanium

After launching the application, i make some code changes. Is relaunching the application necessary each and every time i make a change to the code.

Comment: Can you provide a code?

Comment: no nothing specific to code, just wanted to know that relaunching the application necessary?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Yes, you need to Relaunch again** when you any change make in your code.

But, Some time this is **working without Relaunch**. But not in Home page. This is working when you are using on Sub view and use **URL Property** in **CreateWindow** Object.

But, best way to Relaunch you App always.

May this Information is helpful for you.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

MRT is right As there is Fastdev server(For classic approach) in Titanium which automatically push the changes to your app if there are changes except in app.js ,Also If you are using the Alloy Approach than for speedy development you can use Ti Shadow.

you can find it [Here](https://github.com/dbankier/TiShadow).

Answer (score 1):

Use TIShadow!

It supports rapid deployment and testing of traditional titanium projects and alloy projects